# Cast Type Alias to generic type without the use of package object

Tags: scala, generics, akka, type-alias

I am at the moment writing a repository actor that works similar to the usual List collection but without shifting elements one position to the left on removal. Hence the use of an array.
The only types that this repository will tolerate are those that extend both an Actor and the Indexable type. I want to make use of a Type Alias as a shortcut for this type condition. How do I cast a Type Alias to a generic type inside a class declaration without using a package object as demonstrated below? (See Line #2 and Line #7)

```
package object model {
    type Mob = Actor with Indexable

    object IndexableRepository {
        def create[T <: Mob](capacity : Int) = Props(new IndexableRepository[T](capacity))
    }

    final class IndexableRepository[T <: Mob](val capacity : Int) extends Actor {
        private var indexables = new Array[Mob](capacity)

        def receive : Actor.Receive = {
            case _ => unhandled()
        }

        private def findAvailable(indexables : Seq[Mob]) = {
            (0 to indexables.size) find { idx => indexables(idx) == null }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring the type alias in the companion object:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, Actor}
import IndexableRepository._

final class IndexableRepository[T <: Mob](val capacity : Int) extends Actor {
  private var indexables = new Array[Mob](capacity)

  def receive : Actor.Receive = {
    case _ => unhandled()
  }

  private def findAvailable(indexables : Seq[Mob]) = {
    (0 to indexables.size) find { idx => indexables(idx) == null }
  }
}

object IndexableRepository {
  type Mob = Actor with Indexable

  def create[T <: Mob](capacity : Int) = Props(new IndexableRepository[T](capacity))
}
```

Though, I think `Actor` instances are not meant to be referenced anywhere. Storing them in a collection looks somewhat suspicious.

Comment: I've tried that. Storing the type alias in a companion object does not work because it cannot find it. And what do you mean by storing actors in a collection looks suspicious? This repository does not create actors itself. They are created externally before being passed on to this repository. This repository actor though is for testing purposes as I'm looking for better options such as a custom router.

Comment: @ExecutorService I added some imports. If you import the companion object, the compiler will find the type alias. As for the 'suspicious' you are supposed to interact with actors exclusively through `ActorRef`. You are not supposed to expose any other kind of API directly through a reference of `Actor`. How do you get the references. Because, afaik you cannot instantiate them directly, which also is no accident. If you know what you are doing, you might be ok. Otherwise, I'd recommend reading through akka documentation.

Comment: Oh simple import. Thanks. This repository is supervised by another actor which assigns a type to it like this: `private val someRepository = context actorOf(IndexableRepository.create[SomeIndexable](SIZE))`. After that I would allow the repository to receive messages to add the actor to the collection. The actor to add is of course included in the message itself.